# What does the '?' operator mean in the PropertyChanged statement?

Tags: c#

```
public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    }
```

I am learning C# WPF and I do not understand what the '?' operator means in this sense.. Does this just mean that PropertyChanged event can be null like primitive datatypes?

Comment: Its called [Nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

Comment: @minhtrinhvan: `PropertyChangedEventHandler` is a delegate type, which makes it a reference type, not a value type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A C# `event` is like a property, in that it defines methods on the class that are used to attach and remove event handlers. If you don't specify these methods, they will be generated for you.

If you ignore thread safety, your example is [equivalent to](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQGED2AtgA74B2ApmQC4Cy+wFANgNzIDEZArk0wIYAjJhXRVBw5FADMmGOgDKRCrn4BnVehDoAkgDl81AJYAzAJ4AFAE75iFS9VO4AFnzIBzCsGQBvZOn+YMhQAblTU6FY2dg7Orh7AAKKhNAASrsDClgD8Eda29o4u7p5sSMgAvkA=);

```cs
#nullable enable
public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private PropertyChangedEventHandler? m_PropertyChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged{
        add
        {
            m_PropertyChanged = (PropertyChangedEventHandler?)Delegate.Combine(m_PropertyChanged, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            m_PropertyChanged = (PropertyChangedEventHandler?)Delegate.Remove(m_PropertyChanged, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Now since initially there won't be any registered event handlers, and because both `Delegate.Combine` and `Delegate.Remove` return `Delegate?`. Then the backing field should probably be nullable.

It seems weird that C# allows you to define an event as non-nullable at all. And that the nullability of the field has to be the same as the nullability of `value`.

While this means that `.PropertyChanged += null` will compile, it will have no effect.

There's a related [discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/3016) in "The official repo for the design of the C# programming language".